# Laplace transform of $\sin(\pi|t-1|)$.

Tags: laplace-transform

Hi guys i have to transform this :

> $$\sin(\pi|t-1|)$$

$(0,+\infty)$

I was thinking of multiply it for $u(t-1)$ (leaving the $+$) and then multiplay for $u(t)-u(t-1)$ but changing with the $-$ is this a good way?

Comment: My result is : $e^{-s}$ $(2pi/(s^2+pi^2))$ $+$ $(pi/(s^2+pi^2))$ is correct ? @MarkViola

Comment: do you mean $\sin(\pi|t-1|)$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly :D @nosrati

Comment: I was worried about editing.

Comment: Thk so much , is my result correct @nosrati

Comment: Yes, it is . . .

Comment: Only last doubt... Is e^-s or e^s ? (In the result) @nosrati

Comment: $e^{-s}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perfect , and when i have -sin(pi(t-1))u(t)  i have used the subtraction formula of the sin to get sin (pi t)u(t) is that a correct formula?

Comment: Correct . . . . .